# Linux kernel build for CentOS

Tags: kernel, centos7

I'm trying to build kernel on a system with CentOS (7.3.1611) installed. I downloaded the latest stable kernel (4.10.11) tar.xz file from here: https://www.kernel.org/

Then I ran the below commands:

```
tar xvf linux-4.10.11.tar.xz
cd linux-4.10.11
make nconfig
```

The problem is that when config file is opened, I don't find certain configurations. Also, I see *(NEW)* being appended to a lot of configuration names e.g.

```
[*] 64-bit kernel (NEW)
```

Interestingly, I repeat same steps on another system with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I can see all the required configuration. Also, I don't see this *(NEW)* string being appended to any of the configuration names. It may not be related to the problem I'm facing but it is just an observation.

Any idea why the same kernel source configuration is behaving differently on different machines?

Comment: `I don't find certain configurations.` - Please, provide an example of configuration you cannot find. It looks like on Ubuntu you **already have** `.config` file when you run `make nconfig`. Configuration options which have already existed in `.config` file (even commented out) are not marked as "NEW".

Comment: @Tsyvarev That was an extremely useful hint! :) CentOS originally had 3.10.x version and since the corresponding config was being used (/boot/config-3.10.x) when running "make nconfig", I was not seeing some configurations which are probably the part of newer version of kernel. I used config-4.10.1 from my Ubuntu system and copied to CentOS as .config, and it resolved the issue. Can you add your comment to the response so I can mark it "accepted answer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the comments above. "CentOS originally had 3.10.x version and since the corresponding config was being used (/boot/config-3.10.x) when running "make nconfig", I was not seeing some configurations which are probably the part of newer version of kernel. I used config-4.10.1 from my Ubuntu system and copied to CentOS as .config, and it resolved the issue."